How to Stop Sending the user_engagement Event to Stape Server?
Is there any way to prevent the user_engagement event from being sent to the server? I don't need this event, and it only consumes server requests from Stape.
I tried disabling the user_engagement event through the server-side settings on Stape, expecting it to stop sending unnecessary requests to the server. However, the event is still being sent, consuming server resources that I don't need to use. I'm looking for a way to fully prevent this event from being sent.

If you are using GTM (Google Tag Manager),
go to the trigger tab and create a new trigger like the following photo

and save. then go to you Google Tag or Configuration Tag and modify the trigger and set it to this new customTrigger.

This solution didn't work for me, and I understand it wouldn't work either because using user_engagement as a custom event would only trigger if this event were sent to GTM through the dataLayer. However, this event never reaches GTM.

I wrote if you are using GTM, since I do not know how you are sending the custom events and parameters, you should explain more precisely about your settings

I finally found the solution:
It turns out that if I create an event like page_view instead of using the Google configuration tag, and then add the transport_url parameter with the URL of the Stape server domain, the event is correctly sent without triggering user_engagement.
GA4 Event to Stape Server - Page View
The key is to avoid using the GA4 configuration tag.
I don't have results yet, but I’ll update the answer as soon as I do.
